# Install Windows 7 on USB hard drive and run from it?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Windows OS (Windows 7) on a removable USB hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive)

I know it's imilar to
[Install Windows XP to USB Hard Drive and Run from It](https://superuser.com/questions/68435/install-windows-xp-to-usb-hard-drive-and-run-from-it)
but this time is for Windows 7.

I'm looking for native installations, not virtualization.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this is how you do it](http://www.boot-land.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=6851). I haven't tested it myself though

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's not possible.

Even people that have installed Win7 on an internal disk, then put it into USB enclosure, report an error during the boot (example [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msrgeneraladdin/thread/412519e3-488c-49c9-91cf-73b62f63dd85) from november 18, 2009).