# Can I create a Windows Live installation that runs of an USB stick?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

Is it possible to create a usb bootable version of Windows 7 just like ubuntu??

I mean boot the actual operating system and not the installer from a usb?

Comment: No. See http://superuser.com/questions/68435/

Comment: Please check this answer.
http://superuser.com/questions/392493/is-it-possible-to-create-a-full-windows-7-live-dvd/394098#394098

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using [WinPE](http://apcmag.com/windows_pe_20_a_tiny_version_of_windows_for_system_maintenance.htm) or [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)

This is normally used to create Live CD's, but you can achieve the same result using a USB stick.

Here's an example of a [BartPE installation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BartPE) for Windows XP

[image]

Note that the performance is likely to be pretty crappy unless you use a really stripped version of Windows.

For steps on how to do it: [here's a tutorial](http://www.anewmorning.com/2009/01/15/create-a-live-windows-usb-stick/)

Comment: Oh I just read on the BartPE wikipedia article that the program can't make them for Windows 7: BartPE cannot create Windows Vista, nor Windows 7 Live DVDs.