# Can I run Windows XP from a USB flash drive?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows XP to USB Hard Drive and Run from It](https://superuser.com/questions/68435/install-windows-xp-to-usb-hard-drive-and-run-from-it)

Like Linux, can I run a Windows XP live version from my USB flash Drive?

Comment: Not a legit version of Windows XP.

Comment: Huh? Is BartPE illegit or something? And isn't there also Windows PE itself? It seems like a legit question to me, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: [Can be done](https://web.archive.org/web/20091228061152/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder). (Be prepared for spending a few hours, though.)

If Windows 7 would work instead of Windows XP, you might also want to take a look at the [Windows Automated Installation Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0AEE2B4B-494B-4ADC-B174-33BC62F02C5D), with which you can build Windows PE and put it on a flash drive.

The [reboot.pro](http://reboot.pro/forum/22/) page might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea, as elaborated [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/04/15).

> **Why can't I install Windows on my USB drive?**
>
> A collection of limitations (both
> hardware and software) currently
> prevent Windows from booting and
> running off a USB drive. Some of them
> are described in [this
> whitepaper from WinHEC 2003](https://web.archive.org/web/20031210050448/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/hwdev/bus/usb/usb-boot.mspx).
> Another reason not mentioned in this
> paper is that during any hot-plug
> operation, the USB bus is completely
> reinitialized. Windows really doesn't
> like it when it loses access to its
> boot device. Imagine, you plug in a
> USB camera, the USB bus reinitializes,
> Windows loses access to the boot
> drive, and *oops* the kernel needs to
> page in some data and it can't.
>
> Rats.
>
> But who knows, someday maybe it will
> work.

Comment: Just FYI: this isn't the case for the Preinstallation Environments, because the boot disk is (sort of) the RAM.

Comment: The question is not "Can I run Windows from RAM"