# Windows XP on a USB

Tags: windows-xp, usb

Is there a way to install a Windows XP copy to an USB or are there any modified Windows XP installers that would work on a USB? Not a setup on the USB, an OS on the USB.
Edit: I mean a USB Flash drive

Comment: You might want to look into anything you can find about BartPE.  Any information will be old, but it's designed to boot and run from a CD but might work on a USB device.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a USB".  If you mean USB stick?  flash? disk?.. then say so.  As far as I am concerned, you are trying to install XP on a pair of headphones.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You can easily assume what he means by 'USB' due to the context. There is no need to be so pedantic.

Comment: See this>>>>>https://web.archive.org/web/20091228061152/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run Windows XP from a USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/254209/can-i-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-drive)