# How can I make Windows XP bootable from a flash drive?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb-flash-drive, usb-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows XP to USB Hard Drive and Run from It](https://superuser.com/questions/68435/install-windows-xp-to-usb-hard-drive-and-run-from-it)
>   [Can I run Windows XP from a USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/254209/can-i-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-drive)

I know how to make a bootable flash drive, but when I attempted to make Windows XP boot up it said

```
BOOTMGR is missing.
```

I tried it with two .iso files, but got the same error. What can I do to make Windows XP bootable from a flash drive?

Comment: Windows XP doesn't boot from a flash drive unless you modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) to successfully install Windows XP RTM on an Asus EEE PC 900HD.

Wanted to install a nLite'd version with SP3 slipstreamed but got BSODs on install.  RTM ("SP0") worked OK though.